# How to make text occupy less space in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I am trying to make a diagram of implications that is Y shaped. However, I have text instead of symbols in every implication which takes some space. This makes my diagram extremely wide and it doesn't find inside the page. For reference, this is what I have (including some fix so that it works with Beamer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=small]

        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \ar[dr, Rightarrow]  \& \&  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY \ar[dl, Rightarrow]\\
        \& WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW\ar[d,Rightarrow]  \\ \& ZZZZZZZZZZ \& 
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgot: Welcome to TeX.SE! (BTW, you may want to remove `\[` and `\]` to make your code compilable...)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in section 3.3 of the tikz-cd manual, you may draw some diagrams directly in Ti*k*Z, which may be the simplest option in this case.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\node(X){XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX};
\node[right=0.1cm of X](dummy){};
\node[right=0.1cm of dummy](Y){YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY};
\node[below=of dummy](W){WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW};
\node[below=of W](Z){ZZZZZZZZZZ};
\path[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
(X) edge[commutative diagrams/Rightarrow]  (W)
(Y) edge[commutative diagrams/Rightarrow] (W)
(W) edge[commutative diagrams/Rightarrow] (Z);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, this has the Y-shape. Part of the `YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` gets cut off, which can be remedied by either moving the diagram to the left by brute force (\hspace*{-...}), using a smaller font (e.g. add `font=\small` after `commutative diagrams/every diagram`, or, what I'd recommend, cut down on the content of `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` and  `YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` because this will be appreciated most by the audience.

Answer (score 3):

A pure tikz-cd code with the help of `mathtools` (for its\mathclap` command)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=-0.25em]
       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\ar[dr, Rightarrow, end anchor={[yshift=1.5ex, xshift=-1em]}] \& \& YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY \ar[dl, Rightarrow, end anchor={[yshift=1.5ex, xshift=1em]}]\\
        \& \mathclap{ WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW}\ar[d, Rightarrow] \\ \& \mathclap{ZZZZZZZZZZ} \&
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another simple and shortest solution with `tikz-cd`. After you can use the code of the others excellent users.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
AAAAAAAA \arrow[Rightarrow,rd] &  & BBBBBBBBBBB \arrow[Rightarrow,ld] \\
 & CCCCCCCC \arrow[Rightarrow,dd] &  \\
 &  &  \\
 & DDDDDD & 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```